# Import from xml to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a file which imports data from xml feed to custom mysql table. Xml feed contains tour offers. Database looks like this:

```
#id_tour, #name, #category(e.g. Egypt), #subcategory(e.g. Hurghada),..
```

File that imports data is not located in same folder as wordpress(e.g. import file - www.example.com, wp - www.example.com/wordpress

How can I create a new page/subpage in my import file?

Or what is the best way of importing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I suggest to use plugin here.

Refer Link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately it's paid

Comment: Have you installed plugin ??

Comment: yeah, but free version is useless, but anyway thanks for answer I will accept it